# org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: No capabilities found in request: { "capabilities": { "browserName": "Firefox" } } using Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-grid, geckodriver

I've got a Selenium 3.13 grid running:

Hub Startup:

```
/opt/selenium/jre/bin/java -Dwebdriver.firefox.driver=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver -jar /opt/selenium/server/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar  -host 192.168.109.218 -role hub
```

Node Startup:

```
/opt/selenium/jre/bin/java -Dwebdriver.firefox.driver=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver -jar /opt/selenium/server/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.109.218:4444/grid/register -port 4445 -browser browserName=Firefox
```

I am looking to create a new session using the /wd/hub/session API with the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST "http://192.168.109.218:4444/wd/hub/session" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{  \"Capabilities\": {    \"alwaysMatch\": {      \"browserName\": \"Firefox\",    }  }}"
```

And I receive this error, continually:

```
2021-02-05 14:28:34.284:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp902919927-14: /wd/hub/session java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: No capabilities found in request: {
    "capabilities": {
        "browserName": "Firefox"
    }
}
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of java (openjdk and oracle java) as well as Seleniu 3.9 through the most recent. I've looked through the documentation and don't see anything that I should add or change, but I'm leaning toward the issue being with my capabilities argument.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or slap me across the face with a quick "You're an idiot, here's the easy fix" remark?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the argument `webdriver.firefox.driver` you need to pass:

```
webdriver.gecko.driver
```

Effectively, the startup commands will be:

- Hub:

  ```
  /opt/selenium/jre/bin/java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver -jar /opt/selenium/server/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -host 192.168.109.218 -role hub
  ```
- Node:

  ```
  /opt/selenium/jre/bin/java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/bin/geckodriver -jar /opt/selenium/server/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.109.218:4444/grid/register -port 4445 -browser browserName=Firefox
  ```

Comment: I tried that as well with no change in outcome at all. I'm honestly wondering if there is a particular version of java I should be using with a particular version of Selenium-server.